# Cannot pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish authorization

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to use Facebook login using Firebase authentication. I have followed whole documentation. Lastly whenever I click the login button it gives an error saying:

```
Cannot pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish authorization
```

The line on which it is showing error is:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(LoginActivity.this,Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
```

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? I have looked other answers also but no help from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `logInWithReadPermissions` instead of `logInWithPublishPermissions`. The error message is very clear about that, you are trying to request read permissions with a function that is being used for publish permissions.

Comment: Ahh!!.. That was a silly mistake. My bad. Thank you :)

Comment: you are welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions` is not Firebase Authentication. Signin via federated providers such as Facebook is available via the Firebase JavaScript (web) SDK. See [Authenticate Using Facebook Login with JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login) for details.

> ```
> firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
>   // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
>   var token = result.credential.accessToken;
>   // The signed-in user info.
>   var user = result.user;
>   // ...
> }).catch(function(error) {
>   // Handle Errors here.
>   var errorCode = error.code;
>   var errorMessage = error.message;
>   // The email of the user's account used.
>   var email = error.email;
>   // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
>   var credential = error.credential;
>   // ...
> });
> ```